# How to separate my two appendices from sections

Tags: appendices

I am writing a big file on shared latex, and in the `\backmatter` I include two appendices each of which consist of a `\chapter{Appendix A}` and `\chapter{Appendix B}`. I called those chapter in the thesis.tex file. which mention the following

```
\mainmatter % book mode only
\include{Introduction/introduction}
\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
\include{Chapter3/chapter3}
\include{Chapter4/chapter4}
\include{Conclusions/conclusions}

\backmatter % book mode only
\appendix
\include{Appendix1/appendix1}
\include{Appendix2/appendix2}
```

The problem is that in that file in appendix1 for example I introduce 3 sections as `\section{}` it numbered them .1,.2,.3. When I go to appendix2 and introduce `\section{}` it takes it as .4 and not as .1.

I do not where did I go wrong and I do not get why it is having a point before the number.

Comment: Do not use `\backmatter`. Remove it.

Comment: By the way `\chapter{Wombat}` in the appendix gives you  *A Wombat*. It is really really uncommon (sadly it gets common) to write down Appendix A, Appendix B. It should be *A additional figures*, *B Blueprints* and *C computational chemistry*.

Comment: Thank you Johannes that did the job. But why do some people use \backmatter then?

Comment: I guess because they want unnumbered chapters. For an epilog or something.

Comment: appendices shouldn't usually be part of the `\backmatter`, since they are usually just "differently numbered" chapters.  the bibliography and index(es) *are* back matter components.